# How to create delay in button click, Javascript, Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, onclick, addeventlistener, buttonclick

I am creating an app with Laravel.
I have a page where the content is locked until they accept cookies.
The cookies consent is a div, on top of the content div.
When they click on Accept I would like to fire a POST request which sets up a cookie, and with the same click I would like to remove the div with setting up the element.style.diplay to "none".

When the button is pressed, my cookie is being set up correctly and the div disappears for a second but then it comes back, I figured this must be because of the POST requests reloads the page and overrides the change.
This is my JS function:

```
function removeBlock() {
    const cookieConsent = document.getElementById("cookieWrap");
    cookieConsent.style.display = "none";
}

document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", removeBlock);
```

Can you guys help me with some ideas maybe, how to achieve this?

Thank you

EDIT
this is my set cookie function on my EmailController:

```
public function setCookie(Request $request){
            return redirect('/tasks')->cookie('thecookie', 'cookievalue', $minutes = 1, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = false);}
```

the form in my index.blade.php

```
    <section id="cookieWrap" class="blockedCookie">

        <form class="cookie" action="/tasks" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <h1>Do you accept cookies</h1>
            <div>
                <button id="myBtn">Accept</button>
            </div>
            <button>Reject All</button>
        </form>
    </section>
```

And my route:

```
 Route::post('/tasks', [EmailController::class, 'setCookie']);
```

Comment: If you are making an AJAX request, then that is definitely not the reason. AJAX was made for loading content without reloading the page. However, if you are submitting a form, then that might be the cause of the page reloading.

Comment: Does the cookie contain information about whether the user has consented? Is the consent div visible on the first load even if the cookie is present? And is the cookie readable by JS?

Comment: The code provided looks fine. Are you submitting a form? Can you add the code that performs the POST?

Comment: Ive added all involved code above now.
it is a submit yes.

Comment: Have you considered simply creating a cooking client-side? That would avoid the POST to server and its subsequent page reload: [Document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage to save the status flag like `isAccepted`

Then you can check for the flag onloading and decide whether or not to display the content.

To set flag

```
localStorage.setItem("isAccepted", true);
```

To get flag

```
isAccepted = localStorage.getItem("isAccepted");
if(!!isAccepted){
   #flag is set to true
}
else{
   #flag is false or never set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question:

1. performs a client-side POST request to the server
2. the server creates a cookie and sends a response to the client
3. the client reloads the page

This round trip to the server with its subsequent page refresh can be avoided if the cookie is generated client-side.

```html
<!-- use js-cookie to make things easier -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

  ...

<button id="accept">Accept</button>
```

```js
// set a cookie client-side
//
// this is equivalent to the question's server-side code:
//
//   cookie('thecookie', 'cookievalue', $minutes = 1, $path = null,
//     $domain = null, $secure = false, $httpOnly = false)
//
document.getElementById('accept').onclick = function() {
  const inOneMinute = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1 * 60 * 1000);
  Cookies.set('thecookie', 'cookievalue', {
    expires: inOneMinute,
    path: '',
    secure: false
  });

  // make the UI changes
  removeBlock();
}
```